# getItemId function returns huge numbers - action bar buttons

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am trying to add submenus , I created xml:

```
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:id="@+id/action_overflow"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_overflow"
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
      android:title="@string/action_overflow">
<menu>
<item android:id="@+id/item1" android:title="test"></item>
    <item android:id="@+id/item2" android:title="test2"></item>
        <item android:id="@+id/item3" android:title="test3"></item>
```

```
</menu></item></menu>
```

in mainactivity.java:

```
    @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

 //   int menuid = item.getItemId();

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "id: "+item.getItemId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;

}
```

it shows me numbers like 2131034200...... etc..

please help :(

Comment: help with what?  what's wrong with 2131034200?

Comment: because I have never seen id like this, in all the tutorials I read, I saw "switch" with number 1 , 2 , 3 ... not 202103200

Comment: i solve it
I can use words instead of number, for example


     case R.id.item1: